# How to fix React-Native animation to only animate "this" component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Tile class in a tic-tac-toe game. my goal is to animate the appearance of the tile contents, and only the appearance of the most recently pressed tile. my problem is two-fold:
1: the animation only works for the first tile press, and not every time
2: the animation affects all of the tiles

EDIT: added `value.setValue(0);` to `useEffect()` to reset animated value each press. The only problem that remains is that all the Tile components animate on each press, whereas I only expect an animation for the `<Tile>` component who's `props.contents` changed.

If I instead put the `Animated.timing` function inside `onSelection`, then only the pressed  animates as expected, but since this is over a socket connection, both client's tiles need to animate, and in this case, only the client who pressed the Tile sees the animation. (because the animation function is no longer in `useEffect()` )

EDIT 2: Tried changing `useEffect()` to include dependency array and a conditional statement as well as just including the dependency array as referenced in https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Tile.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SocketContext from "../socket-context";
import { View, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import styles from "../assets/styles/main-style";

function Tile(props) {
  function onSelection(row, col, socket) {
    props.onSelection(row, col, socket);
  }
  let [value] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  // useEffect(() => {
  //  value.setValue(0);
  //  Animated.timing(value, {
  //    toValue: 100,
  //    duration: 10000,
  //    useNativeDriver: true
  //  }).start();
  // });

  (EDIT 2-a):
   useEffect(() => {
    if (props.contents !== {marker: null}) {
      return
    } else {
     value.setValue(0);
     Animated.timing(value, {
       toValue: 100,
       duration: 10000,
       useNativeDriver: true
     }).start();
    }
   }, [props.contents]);

  (EDIT 2-b):
   useEffect(() => {
     value.setValue(0);
     Animated.timing(value, {
       toValue: 100,
       duration: 10000,
       useNativeDriver: true
     }).start();
   }, [props.contents]);

  let animated_opacity = value.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0.0, 1.0]
  });

  let animated_rotation = value.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50, 100],
    outputRange: ["0deg", "180deg", "360deg"]
  });

  return (
    <SocketContext.Consumer>
      {socket => (
        <View style={styles.grid_cell}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.cell_touchable}
            onPress={() => onSelection(props.row, props.col, socket)}
          >
            <Animated.Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: "BungeeInline-Regular",
                fontSize: 65,
                textAlign: "center",
                color: "#fff",
                opacity: animated_opacity,
                transform: [{ rotateX: animated_rotation }]
              }}
            >
              {props.contents.marker}
            </Animated.Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </SocketContext.Consumer>
  );
}

export default Tile;
```

How Tile is used in Grid.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Tile from "../components/Tile";
import styles from "../assets/styles/main-style";

function Grid(props) {
  function onGridSelection(row, col, socket) {
    props.onGridSelection(row, col, socket);
  }

  const grid = props.grid.map((rowEl, row) => {
    const cells = rowEl.map((cellEl, col) => {
      return (
        <Tile
          row={row}
          col={col}
          contents={cellEl}
          onSelection={onGridSelection}
        />

      );
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.grid_row} key={row}>
        {cells}
      </View>
    );
  });
  return <View style={styles.grid}>{grid}</View>;
}

export default Grid;
```

My goal is to have the animation run when the Tile's `props.contents` changes, every time a tile is pressed, and *only* for that tile. I'm not sure if the fact that the entire grid (`props.grid`) is being re-rendered every time a new tile is pressed and that's somehow creating this un-wanted feature.

however, the animation *only* runs for the first tile press. and it runs for every tile that's on the board ( I know this because I have an issue where previous game memory is leaking through to new game ~ a separate issue )

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. Is it that all runs at the same time or just the first one?

Comment: both. I know that it animates all the existing `<Tile>` components because there's a bug where a previous game tile placements will bleed through on the first tile selection of the new game. then all the tiles' appearances are animated. and its only this first press, that the animation runs

Comment: try adding `key` to the `Tile` in `Grid.js`.

Comment: Good catch, however, it didn't help to only animate the currently pressed Tile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your `useEffect` is run on every render since it doesn't have any dependencies supplied as a second argument. The other issue is skipping the effect on first render.

If the  initial value for the tile contents marker is null then you can solve this with something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // exit early if the Tile contents are the initial content values
    // which means the animation shouldn't run
    if (props.contents.marker === null) {
      return;
    }
    value.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(value, {
      toValue: 100,
      duration: 10000,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  // note the addition of the dependency array here so this effect only runs
  // when props.contents.marker changes
  }, [props.contents.marker]);
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects for more info on the second argument to `useEffect`.

Comment: useful information, and the link reminded me about the dependency array. So I tried your suggestion, and there were no changes. the animation still runs on every <Tile>'s text.

Comment: the docs say "React will compare [5] from the previous render and [5] from the next render. Because all items in the array are the same (5 === 5), React would skip the effect." So I also tried adding `[props.contents]` without the condition. that did not work either. animation still ran for all tiles

Comment: @Jim see my edit above to use props.content.marker as the dependency and to skip the effect when that value is null as well. I believe the other edits you posted were having problems due to strict equality checking against objects which is evaluated based on object identity, not value. e.g. `const obj = {key: 'val'}; obj === {key: 'val'};` is false so checking your condition against `{marker: null}` won't work. If contents.marker is a scalar value then I think my edit should fix the issue.